# Beginner help with Old-Style Vehicle Lights

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders, light, height-map

I've been using blender seriously for all of a week now, but I have experience with modeling, texturing, and the generalities of 3D modeling from other programs.

My current project involves texturing an old-style car's tail light and reverse light fixture, which (as I'm sure you all know), uses colored glass over a chrome reflector and halogen bulb.

I'm looking to create the following appearance using textures only (height/normal/etc.), and then to use light to shine through the glass and create realistic refractions.

[image: Text]

What I've been able to achieve thus far is probably **not** the best method, and is also far from accurate:

[image: Text]

[image]

I am willing to learn any procedure and/or method to achieve the accurate result below, and the eventual light pass-through that is my final objective. Thanks so much for your consideration all!

Comment: Hello :). A normal map/bump map seems like a possible solution. What's your current approach?

Comment: can you provide your blend file? so we can see how and what you tried so far?

Comment: Hello @JachymMichal and Chris! thank you both so much for responding! 

My goal is a normal map/bump map, but I don't know how to create one that is as intricate as what is found in real life. Ideally, I would create a normal map in photoshop, but I'm not talented enough to create what I'd need. 

Right now, these materials are very basic BSDFs with some really material settings applied. 

I'll leave a link to my blend file here. Thanks so much for your willingness to help!

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17MxLMr46dVUWaJg2AUIlR8HLMxnMhwyG/view?usp=sharing)